# Probability of an event when rolling a 5-sided die

Tags: probability

Let's assume we have a fair, 5-sided die with the numbers {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}.

Two questions:

1. What is the probability that we never roll a number greater than 4 on a ***single*** roll?
2. What is the probability that we never roll a number greater than 4 when rolling the die an ***infinite number*** of times?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to CV. If this question relates to a class exercise, please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info and add the tag to modify the question accordingly.

Comment: This question does not relate to a class exercise.  It was a question I was asked at work yesterday.

Comment: @Pitouille People are confused when we refer to our self-study criteria in terms of "class exercises" or "textbooks" or whatever.  This is a *routine* question intended to *test* one's knowledge, rather than to solve an actual problem.  That is why, *on its own merits,* regardless of its origin, it is treated here as a self-study question.

Comment: @whuber Thanks, I got it. I will adapt my wording!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting $Y$ be the result of the die roll, the probability that we never roll a number greater than 4 on a single role is $1 - P(Y=5)=\frac{4}{5}$.

When rolling an infinite amount of times, this becomes $(1 - P(Y=5))^\infty = 0$, which should match your intuition - if we roll it enough times, it'll eventually be 5.